# mail-in-a-box versus sendmail?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail, sendmail

What are some of the considerations for selecting between [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) and [Mail-in-a-Box](https://mailinabox.email/)?

[Mail-in-a-Box](https://mailinabox.email/) wins on the marketing:

> What is it?
>
> Mail-in-a-Box lets you become your own mail service provider in a few
>   easy steps. It’s sort of like making your own gmail, but one you
>   control from top to bottom.
>
> Technically, Mail-in-a-Box turns a fresh cloud computer into a working
>   mail server. But you don’t need to be a technology expert to set it
>   up.

That's about my speed.

Alternately, [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) marketing:

> Companies that can afford and/or feel comfortable being outside
>   Industry best practices

On the other hand, sendmail has been around for a very long time.  Generally I prefer to go with the herd.  This is for the immediate purpose of integration with fail2ban on a [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/) Ubuntu instance, although I may use it for something more ambitious down the road.  Also, fail2ban explicitly mentions sendmail in documentation.

**addendum:  mail-in-a-box ships with fail2ban.**

Comment: If you are talking about open source (free) sendmail then I recommend  "keep" policy.  Unless you have sendmail experience consider another open source (free) MTA (postfix/exim/...).

Comment: yes, the free and open source sendmail.  What do you mean by "keep" policy? Keep sendmail *only if* I'm already familiar with it?  Otherwise, consider another MTA?

Comment: Almost exactly.  Sendmail accumulated decades of development.  It's configuration is incredibly flexible **and very complicated**.  As I understand sendmail-8 is going to replaced by Meta1.  Investing a lot of your time in learning advanced sendmail-8 configuration may be not "cost effective".  Without pushing sendmail "to the limits" other MTAs usually are good/better choice.